# Read file line by line storing ints in array

Tags: c, int

Im trying to read a file containing

000101001001010000000000000 (each number is on a new line)

This is the code im using

```
FILE *fatfile;

int i;
i = 0;

fatfile = fopen("fat.dat", "r");
if(fatfile == NULL)
{
    perror("Error while opening file");
}

int number;

while((fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number) == 1) && (i < 32))
{
    fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number);
    fat[i] = number;
    i++;
}

fclose(fatfile);
```

however the output im getting is all 0s

How do i do this correctly

Comment: 1) where is `fat` defined, 2) why are you only storing every second number

Comment: fat is defined further up as fat[32] not sure why im not suppose to be

Comment: each call to `fscanf` reads a number but you only store the number from every second call

Comment: ok where is this error im not sure

Comment: why do you have 2 `fscanf's`: one with `while((fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number) == 1) && (i < 32))` the other on the first line in the loop-body `    fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number);`

Comment: You're calling `fscanf` twice -- once in the `while`, and a second time in the body of the loop. After the second one you store the number into `fat[i]`. So the first one in each time through the loop gets ignored.

Comment: i see the problem now

Comment: To only read 1 digit at a time use `fscanf(fatfile, "%1d", &number)`

Comment: Assuming a 32 bit int, it cannot read a 24 character number.  perhaps using %ld may work for reading those 24 character numbers.  Or are those supposed to be hex numbers?  Then they need to be read as hex values, not int values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while((fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number) == 1) && (i < 32))
{
    // you already read the number from the file above,
    // you need to save it after read the new value.
    // and fscanf is executed every time since it's in the while's condition.
    fat[i++] = number;
```

}

It works like this:

1. check `(fscanf(fatfile, "%d", &number) == 1) && (i < 32)`.
2. If it is true, then it execute its body.

If you read the value again in the loop, you would miss something.

Comment: This still has the same problem: you call `fscanf()` twice for each iteration of the loop.